# Gson annotations with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, annotations, gson

I have a SpringBoot project with Kotlin, and I am using Gson to read and write Json. I am trying to annotate some fields away from Json by custom annotations:

```
data class Order(
    val external: Boolean,
    val orderNumber: String,
    val companyName: String,
    @Exclude val vatCode: String,
)
```

Here is how I define strategy:

```
private final var strategy: ExclusionStrategy = object : ExclusionStrategy {
    override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun shouldSkipField(field: FieldAttributes): Boolean {
        return field.getAnnotation(Exclude::class.java) != null
    }
}
```

And implement it here:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(strategy).create()
```

But it won't work. It seems that annotation is not recognized / cannot be read by strategy functions. What might cause the problem?

Comment: Can you please also share the code for `@Exclude`? Also note that Gson is mainly intended for usage with Java. Might be worth to try other libraries such as [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) or [kotlinx.serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization) which explicitly support Kotlin.

Comment: Resolved this with `@Transient`, though it would have been nice to know why `@Exclude` did not work.

Comment: As mentioned above, without the code for `@Exclude` (or in case it comes from a library, the name of the library) it will be difficult to answer that question. I suspect that this annotation either does not have `RUNTIME` retention, or that its targets are incorrect, e.g. do no contain `FIELD` or contain values which seem to conflict with `FIELD`, e.g. `VALUE_PARAMETER`.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to figure this out, as I'm new to both Java and Kotlin. It appears that for your annotation class to show up in java, you have to add a couple annotations to the annotation itself. For example:

```
@Retention(value = AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class NoSerialize()
```